# How to count total characters, used in the batch file, and output it at the end through the same file?

Tags: batch-file

I need some kind of a script(naming it as "Alpha") which would help me count the total characters used in a batch script(naming it as "Beta")(whose data is appended to a text file) and output the same in the final appended txt file.

If it is possible, could we put Alpha in Beta, and Beta along with its original output would display the characters in Beta in the appended text file.

Regards
AK

Answer (score 1):

Did you make any attempt to research how to do any of this on your own?

TYPE can be used to print out the contents of a file.

```
type beta.bat
```

FIND can be used to compute the number of lines in a file. This command will print the file name, followed by the number of lines

```
find /c /v "" beta.bat
```

You can print just the number of lines by piping the contents of the file into the command

```
type beta.bat | find /c /v ""
```

You can redirect the output of any command to a new file by using the `>` operator

```
echo test >file.txt
```

You can append the output of any command to an existing file by using the `>>` operator

```
echo test2 >>file.txt
```

Perhaps you can use the building blocks above to write your own script.